# angularjs resolve in app.config

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise, resolve

In the following sample I want logincheck to resolve before getting to checkBasket because the latter depends on the previous one. No, I dont want to put the code in the same function because both of these are used many times in another routes. 
Any suggestions on how it should be done?

```
        .when("/bananaBoat", {
            templateUrl: "views/banana.html",
            resolve: {
                logincheck: logincheck,
                checkBasket: checkBasket,
            }
        })
```

Thank you for your help

edit:

here are the functions in resolve:

```
var logincheck = function ($http, $routeParams, $location, $rootScope) {
    var abc = $http.get('/api/resources/getUser');

    abc.then(function (data) {
            if (!($rootScope.user)) {
                $location.url('/');
            }
        }, function () {
            $location.url('/');
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
};

var checkBasket= function ($http, $rootScope, $location, $route) {
    if (!($rootScope.user.basket == ""))
        $location.url("/");
};
```

Comment: i need their result. I have some verifications on checkBasket that depend on logincheck

Answer (score 0):

Resolve will be called before processing every route in resolve you can check user is logged In or not this isLoggedIn variable will be available in controller

```
resolve:{
    isLoggedIn:function(sessionService, $state, $rootScope){
            return sessionService.checksession();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont understand. where is this sessionService comming from?

Comment: 'use strict';

app.factory('sessionService', function($http){
 var return_obj = {};
 return_obj.checksession = function(){
  return $http.post("url to your backend");
 }
    return return_obj;
});

Comment: I'm doing something very different. Check the edit. 
Thank you :)